# "RuntimeException: Could not launch activity...Unable to resolve activity for Intent" when running Jetpack Compose UI tests with createComposeRule

Tags: android, testing, android-jetpack-compose

Running tests with `createComposeRule` and hitting a stack trace like (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not launch activity
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.startActivitySync(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:495)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve activity for: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x14000000 cmp=my.app.package.name.here/android.app.Activity }
...
```

Answer (score 41):

The OP question is about the use of `createComposeRule()` which doesn't require a custom activity (it uses `ComposeActivity` under the hood).

In this case you need to include this below in your gradle file:

```kotlin
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.0.0-beta05")
```

If you take a look at the contents of that package, it's simply an `AndroidManifest.xml` with an `<activity/>` entry for `androidx.activity.ComponentActivity`.

Comment: I've added the 
`debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"`. to solve the problem

Comment: I lost 3 days figuring this out. I thought adding the manifest to androidTestImplementation would have the same effect, but looks like you can't do that. So what this basically does it gives you a custom activity (androidx.activity.ComponentActivity) from which you can run your tests, but you have to include it via debugImplementation.

Comment: FWIW, I had to add it as implementation() after moving some androidTest code into a module

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

```
<activity android:name="androidx.activity.ComponentActivity" />
```

to your manifest.

Comment: I'm running an Android test using createComposeRule() and it works when "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version" is added, as above. I haven't added ComponentActivity to the manifest.

Comment: This is the answer. It is also only necessary to add it to your debug manifest.

Answer (score 2):

You need declare an `Activity` with name `android.app.Activity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` for the Compose UI tests to use to host the content.  Add the following within your `<application>` tag:

```xml
<activity android:name="android.app.Activity" android:theme="@style/your_app_theme_here"/>
```

substituting `your_app_theme_here` with a theme that exists in your app.