# Jetpack Compose take screenshot of composable function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I want to take screenshot of specific composable function on Jetpack Compose. How can I do this? Please, anyone help me. I want to take screenshot of composable function and share with other applications.

Example of my function:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun PhotoCard() {
    Stack() {
        Image(imageResource(id = R.drawable.background))
        Text(text = "Example")
    }
}
```

How to take screenshot of this function?

Comment: At present, there is nothing for this directly in Compose, AFAIK. You can, however, have an `AndroidComposeView` render your composable, then have the `AndroidComposeView` `draw()` its content to a `Bitmap`-backed `Canvas`. That won't cover everything, but it should do as well as "screenshots" of ordinary views. See [this Kotlinlang Slack post](https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1593977883408400?thread_ts=1593041594.083900&cid=CJLTWPH7S) for an example, though it is a couple of months old and will need updating for current versions of Compose.

Comment: @CommonsWare would you mind posting the actual solution? That Slack channel is only accessible to people with a verified Jetbrains account.

Comment: @Maarten: "would you mind posting the actual solution?" -- that Slack thread is about a year old. Pretty much anything about Compose from back then is obsolete. See [this Medium post](https://medium.com/@johannblake/create-bitmaps-from-jetpack-composables-bdb2c95db51) and [corresponding GitHub repo](https://github.com/JohannBlake/bitmap-from-composable) for something much more recent.

Comment: Thank you! This is still interleaving `View` with the composables, would be nice to have easy access to something akin to that `SemanticsNodeInteraction.captureToImage`. I've filed a feature request for it: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/198182887

Comment: See https://github.com/JohannBlake/bitmap-from-composable

Comment: For a multiplatform Kotlin library (also supporting Android Views), see [this](https://github.com/mahozad/comshot).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As [@Commonsware](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) mentioned in the comment, and assuming this is **not** about screenshot testing:

According to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#composition-locals) you can access the view version of your composable function using [`LocalView.current`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/platform/package-summary#LocalView()), and export that view to a bitmap file like this (the following code goes inside the composable function):

```
    val view = LocalView.current
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    handler.postDelayed(Runnable {
        val bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888).applyCanvas {
            view.draw(this)
        }
        bmp.let {
            File(context.filesDir, "screenshot.png")
                .writeBitmap(bmp, Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85)
        }
    }, 1000)
```

The `writeBitmap` method is a simple extension function for File class. Example:

```
private fun File.writeBitmap(bitmap: Bitmap, format: Bitmap.CompressFormat, quality: Int) {
    outputStream().use { out ->
        bitmap.compress(format, quality, out)
        out.flush()
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, can you give more context around this answer?

Comment: Of course, could you please specify which part do you need help with? Please make sure the first code is inside a composable function.

Comment: This solution takes the whole window screenshot, not the region that is rendered for the composable function, ej. taking a screen shot of a composable that have a toolbar, you will have the toolbar also in your screenshot.

Comment: @Akhha8 That's correct, you can get the current composable coordinates through Modifier.onGloballyPositioned {it.positionInRoot().. }, and then use them to crop the bitmap.  

More info on official docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutCoordinates).positionInRoot()


Please let me know if you need more assistance with it. :)

Answer (score 8):

I made a small [library](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Screenshot) that screenshots Composables with single shot or periodically.

A state that is used for capturing and storing Bitmap or ImageBitmap

```
/**
 * Create a State of screenshot of composable that is used with that is kept on each recomposition.
 * @param delayInMillis delay before each screenshot
 * if [ScreenshotState.liveScreenshotFlow] is collected.
 */
@Composable
fun rememberScreenshotState(delayInMillis: Long = 20) = remember {
    ScreenshotState(delayInMillis)
}

/**
 * State of screenshot of composable that is used with.
 * @param timeInMillis delay before each screenshot if [liveScreenshotFlow] is collected.
 */
class ScreenshotState internal constructor(
    private val timeInMillis: Long = 20,
) {
    val imageState = mutableStateOf<ImageResult>(ImageResult.Initial)

    val bitmapState = mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null)

    internal var callback: (() -> Unit)? = null

    /**
     * Captures current state of Composables inside [ScreenshotBox]
     */
    fun capture() {
        callback?.invoke()
    }

    val liveScreenshotFlow = flow {
        while (true) {
            callback?.invoke()
            delay(timeInMillis)
            bitmapState.value?.let {
                emit(it)
            }
        }
    }
        .map {
            it.asImageBitmap()
        }
        .flowOn(Dispatchers.Default)


    val bitmap: Bitmap?
        get() = bitmapState.value

    val imageBitmap: ImageBitmap?
        get() = bitmap?.asImageBitmap()
}
```

ImageResult that contains error or success depending on process result

```
sealed class ImageResult {
    object Initial : ImageResult()
    data class Error(val exception: Exception) : ImageResult()
    data class Success(val data: Bitmap) : ImageResult()
}
```

Composable that captures screenshot of its children Composables

```
/**
 * A composable that gets screenshot of Composable that is in [content].
 * @param screenshotState state of screenshot that contains [Bitmap].
 * @param content Composable that will be captured to bitmap on action or periodically.
 */
@Composable
fun ScreenshotBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    screenshotState: ScreenshotState,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit,
) {
    val view: View = LocalView.current

    var composableBounds by remember {
        mutableStateOf<Rect?>(null)
    }

    DisposableEffect(Unit) {

        screenshotState.callback = {
            composableBounds?.let { bounds ->
                if (bounds.width == 0f || bounds.height == 0f) return@let

                view.screenshot(bounds) { imageResult: ImageResult ->
                    screenshotState.imageState.value = imageResult

                    if (imageResult is ImageResult.Success) {
                        screenshotState.bitmapState.value = imageResult.data
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        onDispose {
            val bmp = screenshotState.bitmapState.value
            bmp?.apply {
                if (!isRecycled) {
                    recycle()
                }
            }
            screenshotState.bitmapState.value = null
            screenshotState.callback = null
        }
    }

    Box(modifier = modifier
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            composableBounds = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                it.boundsInWindow()
            } else {
                it.boundsInRoot()
            }
        }
    ) {
        content()
    }
}
```

Functions for Capturing screenshot. **PixelCopy** is required for Devices with version O and above. And you can use these functions without Composables either

```
fun View.screenshot(
    bounds: Rect
): ImageResult {

    try {

        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bounds.width.toInt(),
            bounds.height.toInt(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,
        )

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            // Above Android O not using PixelCopy throws exception
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314397/java-lang-illegalstateexception-software-rendering-doesnt-support-hardware-bit
            PixelCopy.request(
                (this.context as Activity).window,
                bounds.toAndroidRect(),
                bitmap,
                {},
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            )
        } else {
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
                .apply {
                    translate(-bounds.left, -bounds.top)
                }
            this.draw(canvas)
            canvas.setBitmap(null)
        }
        return ImageResult.Success(bitmap)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return ImageResult.Error(e)
    }
}

fun View.screenshot(
    bounds: Rect,
    bitmapCallback: (ImageResult) -> Unit
) {

    try {

        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            bounds.width.toInt(),
            bounds.height.toInt(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,
        )

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

            // Above Android O not using PixelCopy throws exception
            // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58314397/java-lang-illegalstateexception-software-rendering-doesnt-support-hardware-bit
            PixelCopy.request(
                (this.context as Activity).window,
                bounds.toAndroidRect(),
                bitmap,
                {
                    when (it) {
                        PixelCopy.SUCCESS -> {
                            bitmapCallback.invoke(ImageResult.Success(bitmap))
                        }
                        PixelCopy.ERROR_DESTINATION_INVALID -> {
                            bitmapCallback.invoke(
                                ImageResult.Error(
                                    Exception(
                                        "The destination isn't a valid copy target. " +
                                                "If the destination is a bitmap this can occur " +
                                                "if the bitmap is too large for the hardware to " +
                                                "copy to. " +
                                                "It can also occur if the destination " +
                                                "has been destroyed"
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        PixelCopy.ERROR_SOURCE_INVALID -> {
                            bitmapCallback.invoke(
                                ImageResult.Error(
                                    Exception(
                                        "It is not possible to copy from the source. " +
                                                "This can happen if the source is " +
                                                "hardware-protected or destroyed."
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        PixelCopy.ERROR_TIMEOUT -> {
                            bitmapCallback.invoke(
                                ImageResult.Error(
                                    Exception(
                                        "A timeout occurred while trying to acquire a buffer " +
                                                "from the source to copy from."
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        PixelCopy.ERROR_SOURCE_NO_DATA -> {
                            bitmapCallback.invoke(
                                ImageResult.Error(
                                    Exception(
                                        "The source has nothing to copy from. " +
                                                "When the source is a Surface this means that " +
                                                "no buffers have been queued yet. " +
                                                "Wait for the source to produce " +
                                                "a frame and try again."
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        else -> {
                            bitmapCallback.invoke(
                                ImageResult.Error(
                                    Exception(
                                        "The pixel copy request failed with an unknown error."
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        }
                    }

                },
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            )
        } else {
            val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
                .apply {
                    translate(-bounds.left, -bounds.top)
                }
            this.draw(canvas)
            canvas.setBitmap(null)
            bitmapCallback.invoke(ImageResult.Success(bitmap))
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        bitmapCallback.invoke(ImageResult.Error(e))
    }
}
```

Implementation

```
val screenshotState = rememberScreenshotState()

var progress by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

ScreenshotBox(screenshotState = screenshotState) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .border(2.dp, Color.Green)
            .padding(5.dp)
    ) {

        Image(
            bitmap = ImageBitmap.imageResource(
                LocalContext.current.resources,
                R.drawable.landscape
            ),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(Color.LightGray)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                // This is for displaying different ratio, optional
                .aspectRatio(4f / 3),
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )

        Text(text = "Counter: $counter")
        Slider(value = progress, onValueChange = { progress = it })
    }
}
```

Capturing screenshot

```
Button(onClick = {
    screenshotState.capture()
}) {
    Text(text = "Take Screenshot")
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: This library is awesome. I used it and found it is easy to use. There is only one case I found: If the composable is already created and the screenshot captured, only the visible part will be a part of the result image. For example: if the composable in a LazyColumn and is partially shown. The visible part will be apart of the image.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a test, set the content to that composable and then call `composeTestRule.captureToImage()`. It returns an `ImageBitmap`.

Example of usage in a screenshot comparator: https://github.com/android/compose-samples/blob/e6994123804b976083fa937d3f5bf926da4facc5/Rally/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/compose/rally/ScreenshotComparator.kt

Answer (score 2):

You can get position of a composable view inside the root compose view using `onGloballyPositioned`, and then draw the needed part of the root view into the `Bitmap`:

```
val view = LocalView.current
var capturingViewBounds by remember { mutableStateOf<Rect?>(null) }
Button(onClick = {
    val bounds = capturingViewBounds ?: return@Button
    val image = Bitmap.createBitmap(
        bounds.width.roundToInt(), bounds.height.roundToInt(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
    ).applyCanvas {
        translate(-bounds.left, -bounds.top)
        view.draw(this)
    }
}) {
    Text("Capture")
}
ViewToCapture(
    modifier = Modifier
        .onGloballyPositioned {
            capturingViewBounds = it.boundsInRoot()
        }
)
```

Note that if you have some view on top of `ViewToCapture`, like placed with a `Box`, it'll still be on the image.

p.s. there's a [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/201753237) which makes `Modifier.graphicsLayer` effects, `offset { IntOffset(...) }`(you still can use `offset(dp)` in this case), `scrollable` and lazy views position not being displayed correctly on the screenshot. If you've faced it, please star the issue to get more attention.

Comment: This works well however one issue im finding is if i drag any of my composables to a new position, this method does not pick that up in the screenshot, any idea?

Comment: @alfietap Try adding drag offset value to `translate`. If this doesn't help, ask a separate question with a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.

Comment: I posted a question for you, thank you!

Comment: I used this code to take a screenshot from a view inside Dialog, but it takes a screenshot of the views behind the dialog, any idea ?

Comment: @ZakariaM.Jawas make sure you declare `LocalView.current` inside `Dialog`. These are gonna be two different views when declared inside and outside of dialog content

Comment: this will not work if you use rounded border in a composoble as it will render background as well. and if the background color is different this solution will not work

Answer (score 1):

Using PixelCopy worked for me:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
suspend fun Window.drawToBitmap(
    config: Bitmap.Config = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,
    timeoutInMs: Long = 1000
): Bitmap {
    var result = PixelCopy.ERROR_UNKNOWN
    val latch = CountDownLatch(1)

    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(decorView.width, decorView.height, config)
    PixelCopy.request(this, bitmap, { copyResult ->
        result = copyResult
        latch.countDown()
    }, Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()))

    var timeout = false
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        runCatching {
            timeout = !latch.await(timeoutInMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        }
    }

    if (timeout) error("Failed waiting for PixelCopy")
    if (result != PixelCopy.SUCCESS) error("Non success result: $result")

    return bitmap
}
```

Example:

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val context = LocalContext.current as Activity
var bitmap by remember { mutableStateOf<Bitmap?>(null) }

Button(onClick = {
    scope.launch {
        //wrap in a try catch/block
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            bitmap = context.window.drawToBitmap()
        }
    }

}) {
    Text(text = "Take Screenshot")
}

Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .background(Color.Red)
        .padding(10.dp)
) {
    bitmap?.let {
        Image(
            bitmap = it.asImageBitmap(),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: it takes screen shot of whole view.isnt related with question at all.

Answer (score -2):

You can create a preview function with @Preview , run the function on phone or emulator and take the screenshot of the component.

Comment: OP is asking about taking a screenshot of the Compose rendering programatically.

Answer (score -2):

I was looking for how to take screenshot of a composable in **tests** and this question appeared as the first in results. So, for future users who want to take/save/compare screenshots in tests or do **screenshot testing**, I put my answer here (thanks to [this](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/android-compose-codelabs/blob/main/NavigationCodelab/app/src/androidTest/java/com/example/compose/rally/ScreenshotComparator.kt)).

Ensure you have this dependency along with other Compose dependencies:

```kotlin
debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:<version>")
```

<sup>Note: Instead of the above dependency, you can simply add an *AndroidManifest.xml* file in *androidTest* directory and add `<activity android:name="androidx.activity.ComponentActivity" />` in `manifest` ➜ `application` element.

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67354577/8583692).</sup>

The following is a complete example of taking, saving, reading, and comparing screenshots of a composable function called *MyComposableFunction*:

```kotlin
class ScreenshotTest {

    @get:Rule val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test fun takeAndSaveScreenshot() {
        composeTestRule.setContent { MyComposableFunction() }
        val node = composeTestRule.onRoot()
        val screenshot = node.captureToImage().asAndroidBitmap()
        saveScreenshot("screenshot.png", screenshot)
    }

    @Test fun readAndCompareScreenshots() {
        composeTestRule.setContent { MyComposableFunction() }
        val node = composeTestRule.onRoot()
        val screenshot = node.captureToImage().asAndroidBitmap()

        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        val path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val file = File(path, "screenshot.png")
        val saved = readScreenshot(file)

        println("Are screenshots the same: ${screenshot.sameAs(saved)}")
    }

    private fun readScreenshot(file: File) = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.path)

    private fun saveScreenshot(filename: String, screenshot: Bitmap) {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        // Saves in /Android/data/your.package.name.test/files/Pictures on external storage
        val path = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        val file = File(path, filename)
        file.outputStream().use { stream ->
            screenshot.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream)
        }
    }
}
```

I've also answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69176420/8583692).