# Jetpack Compose not capturing rememberImagePainter in screenshot

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, coil

I'm using the below code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69391397/3585796) to draw my composable function to a canvas which in turn saves the image to the users phone which works fine, until I use `rememberImagePainter` in my `Image` composable and doesn't give me any error message when the app crashes.

```
val bounds = capturingViewBounds ?: return@clickable
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(
    bounds.width.roundToInt(), bounds.height.roundToInt(),
    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
).applyCanvas {
    translate(-bounds.left, -bounds.top)
    view.draw(this)
}
```

I'm loading a PNG image from the web directly into this Image composable based on an if statement. If I use a normal drawable from my folder on the image, there's no issue, it just seems to be when i load an image from the web it crashes

```
Image(
    modifier = Modifier
        .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        .size(48.dp),
    painter = if (player.playerImageUrl.isNotBlank()) {
        rememberImagePainter(data = player.playerImageUrl)
    } else {
        painterResource(
            id = setKitColour(kitColour)
        )
    },
    contentDescription = null
)
```

```
private fun setKitColour(color: String): Int {
    return when (color) {
        "Red" -> R.drawable.ic_shirt_red
        "Blue" -> R.drawable.ic_shirt_blue
        "Green" -> R.drawable.ic_shirt_green
        "Yellow" -> R.drawable.ic_shirt_yellow
        "White" -> R.drawable.ic_shirt_white
        else -> R.drawable.ic_shirt_black
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> doesn't give me any error message when the app crashes

This is not the case, at least in my case I got the following exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Software rendering doesn't support hardware bitmaps

Which is a [known problem](https://github.com/coil-kt/coil/issues/159) in Coil, and can be fixed by specifying `allowHardware(false)`:

Coil **2.0.0** version:

```
Image(
    rememberAsyncImagePainter(
        ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(data = imageURL)
            .allowHardware(false)
            .build()
    ),
    contentDescription = null
)
```

Coil **1.4.0** version:

```
Image(
    rememberImagePainter(
        data = player.playerImageUrl,
        builder = {
            allowHardware(false)
        }
    ),
    contentDescription = "..."
)
```