# With Jetpack Compose, how do I get access to ImageBitmap from an Image composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an `Image` Composable component as in:

```kotlin
Image(
   ...
   bitmap = bitmap
   ...
)
```

That image component is further transformed, scaled and panned. Is it possible to get the resulting `Bitmap` or `ImageBitmap` out of this `Image` component?

Comment: There's no "final bitmap", because transformations are applied on Compose level, and there's no access to how it's getting drawn. But you can capture it as showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69391397/3585796)

Comment: I figured so. I'll check that out, thanks for referencing

Comment: The transformations are made to the surface onto which the Bitmap is drawn and not the bitmap itself. If you want the resulting image, you can capture the composable and draw it into a bitmap image.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Comment: You can use this new multiplatform Kotlin library (also supporting Android Views and Compose Multiplatform): [Comshot](https://github.com/mahozad/comshot)